# How to change the pages for 'register user', 'change password' and 'user edit' in Drupal 8

Tags: forms, routes, user-controls, drupal-8

I wanted to change the pages **'register user'**, **'change password'** and **'user edit'**. 
This is not possible in the Drupal frontend, and you also have to pay a lot of attention in the code.
In forums you will usually find little help and if then rather not
satisfactory.
Therefore, I like to share my solution to save the one or other headache.

Comment: This page is helpful: https://dev.acquia.com/blog/defining-and-altering-routes-drupal-8

Comment: Not sure but 'user edit' seems to be a special case because the route is declared in the entity (Drupal\user\Entity\User).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three forms are already available from Drupal standard, if you want to change them you have to access the route and redirect.

1. For this you first create a module like 'my_forms'.
2. Second the form or a page that you want to hook into the website. e.g. 
   'ForgotPasswordForm'
3. Create a folder inside your my_forms 'Routing' and a file like 'RouteSubscriber.php'

code:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\my_forms\Routing;
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase{
    protected function alterRoutes( RouteCollection $collection ){
        //enter code here
    }
}
```

4. Now you can change the route to the diffrent pages by adding following -

code:

```
//edit the 'forgot password' page
if ( $route = $collection->get( 'user.pass' ) ){
    $route->setDefault( '_form', '\Drupal\my_forms\Form\ForgotPasswordForm' );
}
```

The keyword 'user.pass' allows you to change the routing. setDefault redirects the route to your own form.

```
//edit the 'register' page
if ( $route = $collection->get( 'user.register' ) )
    {
        $route->setDefaults( array(
                                 '_title'      => 'Register',
                                 '_controller' => '\Drupal\myy_forms\Controller\LocalTaskController::offerRegistrationPage'
                             )
        );
    }
```

The keyword for the registration is 'user.register'. By setting the route with setDefault**s** you can also change the name of the link/button. In this case I used a controller to print out a normal page inside the registration. (more at the end of the post)

```
if ( $route = $collection->get( 'entity.user.edit_form' ) ){
    //enter code here
}
```

For the 'user edit' page you need to use the keyword 'entity.user.edit_form'.

5. Last step is to clear your cashes, to register the changes in your Drupal website and refresh your page.

**Load simple page with a Drupal Controller:**

```
namespace Drupal\my_forms\Controller;

class LocalTaskController extends ControllerBase{
/** @var  NodeStorage $nodeStorage */
protected $nodeStorage;
/** @var  EntityViewBuilder $viewBuilder */
protected $viewBuilder;

function __construct( $nodeStorage, $viewBuilder )
{
    $this->nodeStorage = $nodeStorage;
    $this->viewBuilder = $viewBuilder;
}

public static function create( ContainerInterface $container )
{
    $nodeStorage = $container->get( 'entity.manager' )->getStorage( 'node' );
    $viewBuilder = $container->get( 'entity_type.manager' )->getViewBuilder( 'node' );

    return new static( $nodeStorage, $viewBuilder );

}

public function offerRegistrationPage()
{
    $node        = $this->nodeStorage->load( 24 );
    $renderArray = $this->viewBuilder->view( $node );

    return [
        '#type'   => '#markup',
        '#markup' => render( $renderArray ),
    ];
}
```

The '24' is the nid of the simple page, which should be displayed instead of the standard registration.